# Swfupload suddenly stopped working in IE (with flash 10 and windows 7)

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, swfupload

In our backend-application we make 
extensive use of swfupload. It has always worked perfectly and we're 
really appreciating the efforts of the swfupload team. Unfortunately, 
we keep getting more and more complaints from our customers, saying 
the uploader doesn't work anymore in their browser (Internet 
Explorer). The 'select files' button appears as an empty square, with 
a red cross.

I've spent hours trying to fix this, because also on my computer it 
doesn't work anymore. I'm using Windows 7 + Internet Explorer 8 + 
Flash 10.2. I've disabled all of my security settings, but no effect. 
So I thought, it's because of a wrong implementation, but if I go to 
http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/simpledemo/, I get the same result. 
Also, the demo's in the latest beta3 package seem to have the same 
problem.

I hear and see a lot of people complaining about this, but can't seem 
to find a proper solution or any response from the swfupload team. Is 
swfupload dead? Should I choose another tool? Any other people with 
the same problem?

I also placed this question on the swfupload forums, but I'm not really counting on answers over there.. http://groups.google.com/group/swfupload/browse_thread/thread/344a9079330dd805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the response I got from one of the swfupload developers, thought I'd share it with other people searching for a solution (there is none):

"We have users with the same problem (on Windows 7, IE 8 32-bit, Flash
10.1 as I recall it) and we have tried many different suggestions found in various forums but without success. Eventually we had to recommend the users to switch to Firefox."

So, to me, it looks like swfupload is a dead end..

Comment: I had the same issue(win7 IE 64bit) and simple solved the issue by upgrading my flash. Maybe you need: http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/2140

Comment: Don't know if this is solved yet, but I've had tons of complaints from various customers with various setups about swfupload. I actually think using Flash for uploading files was a bad idea anyway! So I'd suggest people to look for decent alternatives. I personally find qqUploader a good one, using solely javascript, very friendly to use.

Comment: Yeah there are millions of different options, especially with HTML5. I had a quick look and http://www.uploadify.com/ HTML5 version has the best reviews.